# Asymptotic distribution of Kernel density estimator

Tags: references, proof, asymptotics, kernel-smoothing

For my research I am looking for proof of the asymptotic distribution of the univariate Kernel density estimator as proposed by Rosenblatt 1956 and Parzen 1962. A proof is for example given [here](http://faculty.arts.ubc.ca/vmarmer/econ590a/nonparametric.pdf) and is also included in [Nonparametric Econometrics](http://books.google.com/books/about/Nonparametric_Econometrics.html?id=m2soVgsuMgMC) by Pagan and Ullah. But since I am not writing about an economics topic I would like to cite a more "original" source. Does somebody know the paper in which the proof occurred first? Or an more basic math book would also be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I believe we should give credit to **Parzen (1962)** for the first comprehensive and self-contained treatment of the fundamentals of univariate kernel density estimation, in
[Emanuel Parzen (1962), "On Estimation of a Probability Density Function and Mode", *The Annals of Mathematical Statistics*, Vol. 33, No. 3](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2237880)

In fact it is his equation $(1.7)$ that must contain for the first time what has become the archetypal notation for the kernel density estimator, (copying from the original)
[image]

In this paper, he also proves the asymptotic normality of the estimator, alongside other basic properties.

PS: [Rosenblatt, M. (1956). "Remarks on Some Nonparametric Estimates of a Density Function". The Annals of Mathematical Statistics. 27 (3): 832.](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177728190)
precedes Parzen, but is less accessible.